# Handling dimensions for RGB data with Keras CNN

Tags: keras, cnn

I'm trying to make work the code from Keras' documentation [getting started](https://keras.io/getting_started/intro_to_keras_for_engineers/). There is something I do not understand about handling RGB data. I made one work with MNIST data (which is greyscaled), but I can't seem to figure out the CIFAR10.

```
HEIGHT = 200
WIDTH = 200
def build_model():


    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3))

    # making things simple, I don't CenterCrop, just set the input to whatever I'm feeding it
    # I do rescale to 0-1 values
    x = Rescaling(scale=1.0 / 255)(inputs)

    # this basically the doc's architecture
    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", )(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu",)(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu",)(x)
    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model


# fake data, easier to play with shapes  than with the actual CIFAR10 data to debug
# shape is (500, 200, 200, 3), cifar10's is (60000, 32, 32, 3)
data = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(500, HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3)).astype("float32")
# shape is (500,1) cifar10's is (60000,1). Just 10 categories to match the output layer
labels = np.random.randint(0,9, size=(500,1)).astype("int8")

print("got fake data... ")
model = build_model()
print("model built... ")
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-3),
              loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy())
print("model compile...")
model.fit(data, labels)
print("done")
```

For some reason, I get:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible
```

Strangely, if change the label's fake data to `size=(500, 10)` then it "works". But obviously, that makes no sense, since it would mean I have 10 labels for each sample. The MNIST dataset that works which I refer to can also be found in the linked documentation. The architecture of the network is much simpler (only Dense layers linked together).

What am I missing here? Why would it be so different for a colored image than it is for a greyscale?

I also tried the work with the data from     `train, test = cifar10.load_data()`, but it yields the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Strangely, if change the label's fake data to `size=(500, 10)` then it "works". But obviously, that makes no sense, since it would mean I have 10 labels for each sample.

It would most certainly **not** mean that; it simply means that, for the type of softmax classification you are attempting here with `CategoricalCrossentropy` loss, your labels should be **one-hot encoded**, and not single digits, as here (hence the error).

You should

- **Either** convert your single-digit `labels` to one-hot encoded ones using `to_categorical` ([docs](https://keras.io/api/utils/python_utils/#tocategorical-function))
- **Or** change your loss to sparse categorical cross-entropy ([docs](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#sparsecategoricalcrossentropy-class))

Changes in your code for the first approach:

```
labels_ohe = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes=10)
# [...]
model.fit(data, labels_ohe)
```

Changes in your code for the second approach:

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-3),
              loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy())
```

> The MNIST dataset that works which I refer to can also be found in the linked documentation.

The MNIST labels, like the CIFAR10 ones, are also single-difit integers and not one-hot encoded; your MNIST model from the [example](https://keras.io/getting_started/intro_to_keras_for_engineers/#training-models-with-fit) you refer to you works because of the `loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy"` setting.